# Wordpress - add description to drop down menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been trying to get the description for the parent menu item to show up to the right of the drop-down menu.

Like this:

[image]

But I cannot get the description to show up there at all. I have followed several tuts on this, including: [This one](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output) that seems to have the same code as the other 5 or so I've seen.

I tried using the `$item->description` but I'm not sure where that get's populated in the walker class. I tried just reformatting the output, but to no avail.

Here is what I have:

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
      function start_lvl(&$output, $depth, $item) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<section class=\"sub-menu col-12\"><div class=\"nav-info col-8 right\"><p>". $item->description ."</p></div>";
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu-list col-4\">\n";
      }
    }
```

Everything works fine except there is no description where it says `$item->description`. I know there is a description set in wordpress, but it's not showing up.

What I need to know, I think, is where I pull the description from. The walker works, but the only think not showing up is the description.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of guesswork, and research, I've found the answer!

Using the tutorial I was looking at previously, I realized I needed to use separate methods in the class in order to add the description AND give the sub-menu `ul` a custom class.

Here is the part that adds the description where it's needed, before the sub-menu.

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            global $wp_query;
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

            $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

            $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

            $item_output .= $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= "\n$indent<section class=\"sub-menu col-12\"><div class=\"nav-info col-8 right\"><p>" . $item->description . "</p></div>\n";
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

        }
```

Afterwards, I used this method to give the sub-menu my custom class.

```
        function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu-list col-4\">";
        }
```

The problem was now that the formatting was off. An extra `div` kept showing up, and I realized I was never closing the `section` element, that would have normally been closed when used in the `start_lvl` method. Since it was in the `start_el` method it was not closing. So, I added this at the end to make sure both the `ul` and `section` would close properly.

```
        function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "\n$indent</ul></section>";
        }
    }
```

Now the description shows up as desired. Thank you to @Iliya Reyzis for your input. While it did not directly help me, I appreciate you attempting to help me.

Comment: I just wrote a tutorial on this in case anyone needs it in the future. More details in the tut than what I posted here. http://vincilione.com/wordpress-navigation-description/

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding new walker, you need to bind it to your menu - wp_nav_menu() in the `walker` parameter like shown in the example -

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
 'container' =>false,
 'menu_class' => 'nav',
 'echo' => true,
 'before' => '',
 'after' => '',
 'link_before' => '',
 'link_after' => '',
 'depth' => 0,
 'walker' => new description_walker())
 );
```

or you can filter all the menus `walker` parameter by

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args' , 'my_description_walker' );
function my_description_walker( $args ) {
    $args['walker'] = new description_walker;
    return $args;
}
```

`description_walker` is the name of the walker

you can try this walker and figure it out

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
     function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);
            $output .= sprintf('<i>%s</i>', esc_html($item->description));
        }
}
```

Comment: Why would your use of `$item->description` work, but not mine? My walker works fine aside from the description not showing up at all. It populates my custom classes, etc to the navigation menu as well as the custom format. Just no description.

Comment: Thanks for the answer BTW. I'm going to test it when I get back to work in the morning!

Comment: I may be missing something, but I'm using your code and the description is still not there.